# Scope class name and script per angular component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component which is repeated various times on a page. I am implementing the `AutoNumeric` library and need to pass a selector to the function. However, the selector needs to be unique per instance of the component, so the first instance would be `cssClass-1` and the second instance `cssClass-2`, and the js inside the component would know which selector to look for.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FieldType } from '@ngx-formly/material';
import AutoNumeric from 'AutoNumeric';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-currency-type',
  template: `
  <div class="cssClass-1">
    <input
      matInput
      [formControl]="formControl"
      [formlyAttributes]="field"
      autocomplete="false"
      type="text"
    />
    </div>
  `,
})

export class CurrencyTypeComponent extends FieldType implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    const anElement = new AutoNumeric('.cssClass-1 > input', {
        allowDecimalPadding: false,
        caretPositionOnFocus: "start",
        currencySymbol: "£",
        decimalPlaces: 0
      });
  }
}
```

I can't find a way to scope the script to just this instance of the component, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the class name a JS variable so it can be changed for each instance.

If you are happy with random strings maybe use [a uuid library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid).

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FieldType } from '@ngx-formly/material';
import AutoNumeric from 'AutoNumeric';
const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-currency-type',
  template: `
  <div [ngClass]="cssClass">
    <input
      matInput
      [formControl]="formControl"
      [formlyAttributes]="field"
      autocomplete="false"
      type="text"
    />
    </div>
  `,
})

export class CurrencyTypeComponent extends FieldType implements OnInit {

  // initialize empty by default  
  public cssClass = '';

  ngOnInit() {

    // generate new random string
    const cssID = uuidv1();

    // prefix required as class names can't start with numbers
    const cssPrefix = "cur--";

    this.cssClass = cssPrefix + cssID.toString();

    // use string interpolation
    const anElement = new AutoNumeric(`${this.cssClass} > input`, {
        allowDecimalPadding: false,
        caretPositionOnFocus: "start",
        currencySymbol: "£",
        decimalPlaces: 0
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: It's probably worth adding that a css class can't start with a number, I've had to amend your solution slightly to prefix the uuid that is generated with an alpha character.

Comment: great sam . well done. If you want to suggest an edit to my answer I will accept. well done again. cheers